# Why "Cannot read property 'value' of null" error is popping in error log of JavaScript? How to resolve it?

Tags: javascript

Please let me know the solution.

[After executing the snippet in JavaScript page, error is populating.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivFze.png)

Comment: Perhaps you added the `element` dynamically. Then search again after the add.

Comment: have you tried using jpeg instead of png?

Comment: You should include the actual code into your question instead of posting it in images.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Post the actual code.

Comment: If possible console error also.

Comment: It is better to post your code via fiddle (like: https://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce the error and give solutions.

Comment: Eh, another js/jquery mash up :s

Comment: @imEnCoded, no, it is better to include the code in the question itself. The `<>` button in editor can be used to create a [MCVE] within StackOverflow without the need to go to an additional site.

Answer (score 1):

[image: in param variable add para name account not be declare and same cat priority are not initialize]

assign variable used in single quote and not declare var used to assign var into declare var

for example var par may be like as

```
Param = { 'account': acc,'Solution': sol ,'cat': category, 'priority':prior:
```